# Add minutes to current time

Tags: php, date

I am trying to add minutes to current date but it returns strange results

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');

$currentDate = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
$currentDate_timestamp = strtotime($currentDate);
$endDate_months = strtotime("+10 minutes", $currentDate_timestamp);
$packageEndDate = date("m-d-Y H:i:s", $endDate_months);

echo " <br> " . $packageEndDate . " <br> ";
echo $currentDate;
```

I am getting Output

```
01-01-1970 05:50:00
07-19-2013 20:25:23
```

It should return

```
07-19-2013 20:35:23
07-19-2013 20:25:23
```

After this I need to query to database so date format should be same. Database column is of string type.

Comment: Why you don't not add 600 seconds directly ? I think it'll also use less resources.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is redundant. Why format a timestamp as a string, then convert that string back to a timestamp?

Try

```
$now = time();
$ten_minutes = $now + (10 * 60);
$startDate = date('m-d-Y H:i:s', $now);
$endDate = date('m-d-Y H:i:s', $ten_minutes);
```

instead.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the minimalist way would be:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Baku');

$packageEndDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+10 minute'));
echo $packageEndDate;
```

Output (Current time in my city at the time of writing):

```
2017-07-20 12:45:17
```

Answer (score 0):

Pakistan, which is the localisation explicitly set, uses "DD-MM-YYYY" format dates so the problem occurs when you cast the date into a string of "MM-DD-YYYY". This American format of date is not parseable by the Pakistan localisation.

If you still want to keep the round-trip to a string and back, use DD-MM-YYYY or the ISO datetime format.

While this is the only (current) answer which actually explains your original issue, I recommend the code be refactored as others have demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$now = time();
$tenMinFromNow = date("m-d-Y H:i:s", strtotime('+10 minutes', $time));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tenMinsFromNow = (new \DateTime())->add(new \DateInterval('PT10M'));
```

Will leave you with a [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) object representing a time 10 minutes in the future. Which will allow you to do something like:-

```
echo $tenMinsFromNow->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/U8rZi)

PHP version >= 5.4 I'm afraid, but you should be using at least that version by now anyway.